# Combining map values in Java 8 with streams

Tags: java

I have two `Map`s that are supposed to have the same keys (assumption).

I need to perform an action on corresponding elements

Java 7 code:

```
Map<X,Y> m1, m2;

for (Map.Entry<X,Y> kvp: m1.entrySet()) {
    K key = kvp.getKey();
    Y value1 = kvp.getValue();
    Y value2 = m2.get(key);    


    doSomething(value1, value2);
}
```

My target is to use a lambda for such operation

Something like

```
Map<X,Y> m1, m2;

[initStreamHere](m1, m2).forEachCorrespondingEntry((k, v1, v2)-> doSomething(v1, v2));
```

In general, it could be cool if `v1` or `v2` is null or not according to the presence or not of the corresponding key.

Does Java provide any such cool feature? Or is it possible to implement with custom code in less than 50 lines?

My goal is to use a lambda expression that takes the key and the two corresponding values

Comment: Just `forEach` over `m1`, capture `m2` using `get` with the `m1` key provided by the `forEach` and call your `doSomething`.

Comment: Uhmmm... I was just asking if Java could take care of the lookup on m2 and *serve* me the results :-) I have already implemented the code the old Java 7 fashion. PS it is useless to stream on m1 and need to get on m2, I would have showed my boss an impressive example otherwise

Comment: Create a `MultiMap` from the two maps and stream those results. Or create your own `Map` with two values and stream that (so you don't have to deal with a `Collection` or `List` value).

Comment: I think your loop is just fine the way it is. Streams are (currently) for single values separately. Use loops for handing multiple values at once.

Comment: FYI some IDEs will alert you when you can move from a loop to a lambda. which can be quite helpful for teaching / learning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as it's only curious question. For production/your colleagues it's better to write something much more understandable.

```
interface EntryConsumer<K, V> {
    void apply(K key, V v1, V v2);
}

public static <K, V> void fancyStreams(Map<K, V> m1, Map<K, V> m2, EntryConsumer<K, V> consumer) {
    Stream
        .concat(m1.entrySet().stream(), m2.entrySet().stream())
        .filter(e -> e.getValue() != null) // filter out nulls
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey))
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .filter(e -> e.getValue().size() == 2) // filter out non-matching key-values
        .forEach(e -> consumer.apply(e.getKey(), e.getValue().get(0).getValue(), e.getValue().get(1).getValue()));
}

public static <K, V> void plainOldIteration(Map<K, V> m1, Map<K, V> m2, EntryConsumer<K, V> consumer) {
    m1.entrySet()
        .forEach(e -> {
            if (m2.containsKey(e.getKey())) 
                consumer.apply(e.getKey(), e.getValue(), m2.get(e.getKey()))
        });
}

// Actual usage
Map<String, Integer> m1, m2;
m1 = Maps.of("1", 22, "2", 23);
m2 = Maps.of("1", 20, "2", 19, "3", 21);
fancyStreams(m1, m2, (k, v1, v2) -> System.out.println(k + ": " + (v1 + v2)));
plainOldIteration(m1, m2, (k, v1, v2) -> System.out.println(k + ": " + (v1 + v2)));
```

And your actual request (a little bit more verbose)

```
public class EntryStream<K, V> {

    private final Map<K, V> m1;
    private final Map<K, V> m2;

    private EntryStream(Map<K, V> m1, Map<K, V> m2) {
        this.m1 = m1;
        this.m2 = m2;
    }

    public static <K, V> EntryStream<K, V> of(Map<K, V> m1, Map<K, V> m2) {
        return new EntryStream<>(m1, m2);
    }

    public void forEachCorrespondingEntry(EntryConsumer<K, V> consumer) {
        m1.entrySet()
            .forEach(e -> {
                if (m2.containsKey(e.getKey())) consumer.apply(e.getKey(), e.getValue(), m2.get(e.getKey()));
            });
    }
}

// Usage
EntryStream.of(m1, m2).forEachCorrespondingEntry((k, v1, v2) -> System.out.println(k + ": " + (v1 + v2)));
```

Comment: Incredibly close. I don't need to implement all the logic with lambdas, I need the "interface" in lambdas. So as long as I can write `forEachCorrespondingEntry((k, v1, v2) ->` it's great. If the backing implementation uses stream or plain old loops it will be just fine

Comment: Why EntryStream isn't exactly what you need? Btw, it's easy to generalize to more than two maps

Comment: No sorry I was talking about the chain invocation on your first fragment

Comment: Guess first fragment can be removed as long as it's not that you need

Answer (score 0):

Here I wrote nice example of how you can use merge function for your purposes.

```java
public class MapCombine {
    
    public static Map<String,Integer> combineMaps(Map<String,Integer>map1,Map<String,Integer>map2){
        map2.forEach((key,value)->{
            map1.merge( key, map1.get(key), MapCombine::combine);   
        });
        return map1;
    }

    public static int combine(Integer a , Integer b) {
        return a+b;
    }
    
    public static void main (String ...args) {
        Map<String,Integer>map1 = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String,Integer>map2 = new HashMap<>();
        map1.put("Red", 1);
        map1.put("Blue", 12);
        map1.put("Black", 11);
        map2.put("Red", 1);
        map2.put("Blue", 111);      
        
        // This will print total for each color
        System.out.println(combineMaps(map1, map2));
    }
}
```

Here is the output: {Red=2, Blue=24, Black=11}

Answer (score -1):

Something like this ?

```
m1.entrySet()
  .stream()
  .filter(kvp -> m2.containsKey(kvp.getKey()))
  .forEach(kvp -> doSomething(kvp.getValue(), m2.get(kvp.getKey())));
```

Comment: No sorry, I wanted to have a lambda that takes all the 3. I am asking the entire question for curiosity and fun, not because I am stuck into something :-)